# Using the complex exponential function to calculate the $\sin(30^{\circ})$

Tags: complex-numbers, approximation

I need help with the calculation of the following function
$$\sin(\omega t)=\frac{(e^{iωt}-e^{-iωt})}{2j}\implies \sin(30^{\circ})= \sin\left(\frac \pi 6 \right) = \frac{e^{\frac \pi 6 i}-e^{-\frac \pi 6i}}{2i} $$...when I plug in the values for the function in my program code it replays $0.53\dots$ But it should do $0.5000000$

Is it because the approximation with two e's and the other numbers with commas divided by $2$ include an such a high error in it(the numbers are not ending) so that i would have to use a Taylor polynomial (it is the aim to use function that can be written as only + and - for schemas. Functions with a sine in it are too abstract and not allowed) for calculating the sine without precalculated values like in a cordic function.

Ps. Please do not write it as Taylor polynomial or cordic.

Comment: It may well be that your calculator is doing degrees instead of radians, or the other way around. You must define this with the MODE key on the calculator.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange community! The quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will help you get the most benefit from your time here. Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your equations.

Comment: Note that $30^\circ = 30\times \pi/180 = \pi/6$ radians. Therefore, $\sin(30^\circ) = \frac{e^{i\pi/6}-e^{-i\pi/6}}{2i}$.

Comment: I did like this(it was programmed in python and js)....when i put more 0s to i it approximated to 0.5??(from 0.53 to 0.52)...??

Comment: maybe you want to post your script on a programming site instead? this is mainly for mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(30^\circ) = \sin \frac{\pi}{6}$.  So in  your formula, use $\omega t = \frac{\pi}{6}$.

\begin{align}
e^{j\pi/6} &\approx 0.8660254040+j \;0.5000000000
\\
e^{-j\pi/6} &\approx 0.8660254040-j \;0.5000000000
\\
\frac{e^{j\pi/6}-e^{-j\pi/6}}{2j} &\approx 0.5000000000
\end{align}